# Выпадающее меню ширина во весь экран

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Как сделать выпадающее меню ширину на весь экран 
http://jsfiddle.net/3xryx/

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="ddmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Миссия</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Команда</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">История</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Продукты</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Логитипы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Шаблоны</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Иконки</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Плагины jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">маркетинг Internet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Интернационализация</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Китай</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Япония</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Канада</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Автсралия</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Южная Америка</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакт</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#ddmenu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8aa8bd;
}

#ddmenu li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #dae0e5;
}

#ddmenu li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 12px;
  line-height: 78px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6c87c0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#ddmenu li:hover > a {
  color: #7180a0;
  background: #d9e2ee;
}

#ddmenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#ddmenu ul:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 8px;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent;
}

#ddmenu ul:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 4px;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
}

#ddmenu ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
}

#ddmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 7px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#ddmenu ul li a:hover {
  background: #e9edf3;
}
```

JS:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#ddmenu li').hover(function() {
      clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
    }, function() {
      $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
      }, this), 100));
    });

  }); < /script>
```

Comment: т.е аддаптивное меню?

Comment: чтобы width:100% был . Но с процентами не работает   . Каждое меню открывается под li , а я хочу чтобы был width:100% т.е. не под li

Comment: @fikos, вам нужно, чтобы ячейки растягивались на весь экран?

Comment: @likerRr да , вот как в этом сайте kadinextra.com

Comment: @fikos, http://jsfiddle.net/3xryx/5/ , так?

Comment: а это не одно и тоже ? @likerRr

Comment: @fikos, смотрите сами, ваш вариант: http://clip2net.com/s/ibXgJL, мой вариант: http://clip2net.com/s/ibXi3L

Comment: дело в не категориях . Дело в под категориях, в  выпадающем меню @likerRr

Comment: @fikos, ох, извините за невнимательность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, так? http://jsfiddle.net/3xryx/6/

Comment: Спасибо большое @likerRr

Answer (score 0):

Перейдите по своей ссылке, и там, где у вас поле для вставки `javascript` уберите `<script type="text/javascript"> и </script>`, затем нажмите кнопочку Run вверху, все, Профит.